# How to compare the output of two binary files when the input is redirected to a file?

Tags: linux, bash, shell

I have two compiled C files that I am trying to compare in  a shell script to see if they produce the same output when the input for both is redirected to another file called test.txt. I have to make sure my code does the following:

However, I don't think that my code is correct. I think that I'm missing something regarding the input redirection part.

This is what I have so far:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

if [ -e test-code ] 
then
    ./test-code > test1.txt 
    ./gold-code > test2.txt
    diff -w test1.txt test2.txt < test.txt

    if [ $? -eq 0 ]
    then
        exit 0
    fi
else
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: It sounds like it's `test-code` and `gold-code` that should have `test.txt` as their input. Not `diff`.

Comment: @thatotherguy But then don't I have to compare the output of both files also? So, then after comparing the output with diff I should do  `./test-code < test.txt | ./gold-code < test.txt` inside the if statement after the diff?

Comment: Add `else; exit 1; fi` to inner `if`. Also you can do `if diff -w ...` instead of checking `$?`.

Comment: @user7231 I actually tried to do the `if [ diff -w test1.txt test2.txt ]` before but I got an error that said [ : too many arguments.

Comment: @Gray `if diff` and `if [ diff` are two different things. `[` is a command name (have a look at `/usr/bin/[`). `ls diff -w file1 file2` makes no sense, and neither does `[ diff -w file1 file2 ]`

Comment: Your description is unclear.    However, I suspect changing the two command lines to `./test-code < test.txt > test1.txt` and `./gold-code < test.txt > test2.txt` might fill the need (i.e. run the two programs with the same input, and capture their outputs to separate files for comparison).   Although you have assumed `gold-code` exists, might also pay to check that it does.

Comment: You might need `diff -b` instead of `diff -w`.  When `-b` is used, ' Ignore changes in the amount of white space' compared with `-w` 'Ignore all white space' (man pages from macOS).  It depends on whether your directive "when ignoring white space differences" means "`a b c`" and "`abc`" are to be treated as the same or as different, compared with "`a  b  c`" and "`a b c`".

Comment: It's better to use `cmp` util rather `diff` as far you are not interested in an actual difference... especially for bynary files.

Comment: I think you want `diff -w <(./test-code < test.txt) <(./gold-code < test.txt)`

Comment: You have pure bash code. Where is the relation to C language? It doesn't matter with which language your programs were written as you only use the output of them.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several errors, try this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e # every command that fails does exit $?
[ -e test-code ] 
./test-code < test.txt > test1.txt 
./gold-code < test.txt > test2.txt
diff -w test1.txt test2.txt
```